# Gradle. Can't build simple Android Project

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have starting to learn a Gradle and try to make a first **build.gradle** file

```
println 'Build start.'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4'
    }
}
println 'Current gradle version : '+gradle.gradleVersion
apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 15
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs ['src','src_default']
            res.srcDirs ['res']
        }
        androidTest.setRoot('tests')
    }
}
```

#### After `gradle build` :

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.
     Required by:           
         :hello_gradle:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/0.4/gradle-0.4.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated

* Try:                      
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
```

#### After `gradle clean` :

```
* Where:                    
Build file '/home/sergey/Documents/dev_master/hello_gradle/build.gradle' line: 11

* What went wrong:          
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'p4_common_platform'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
   > Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
```

#### After `gradle clean --stacktrace` :

```
* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'p4_common_platform'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:54)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:148)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:39)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:59)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:504)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:83)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:129)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
    at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
    at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
    at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:117)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.access$200(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction$3.run(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.execute(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:131)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractPluginAware.apply(AbstractPluginAware.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.Project$apply$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectScript.apply(ProjectScript.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.Script$apply$0.callCurrent(Unknown Source)
    at build_362n2fdy03onxvkm655devi4f.run(/home/sergey/Documents/dev_master/p4_common_platform/build.gradle:11)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:52)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: org.gradle.api.plugins.PluginInstantiationException: Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:71)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.providePlugin(DefaultPluginContainer.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.addPluginInternal(DefaultPluginContainer.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginContainer.apply(DefaultPluginContainer.java:103)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.applyPlugin(DefaultObjectConfigurationAction.java:115)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/gradle/api/artifacts/result/ResolvedModuleVersionResult
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.$getStaticMetaClass(AppPlugin.groovy)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin.<init>(BasePlugin.groovy:1627)
    at com.android.build.gradle.AppPlugin.<init>(AppPlugin.groovy:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.DependencyInjectingInstantiator.newInstance(DependencyInjectingInstantiator.java:48)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultPluginRegistry.loadPlugin(DefaultPluginRegistry.java:69)
    ... 45 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gradle.api.artifacts.result.ResolvedModuleVersionResult
    ... 50 more
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: can you also copy paste your app build.gradle?

Comment: You probably need to use a later version of android gradle plugin, 0.4 is too old and probably has been removed from maven central. Checkout http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide for guide.

Comment: I'm struggling with this stuff too. I thought maven was replaced with jcenter?  How did you resolve the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several attempts trying to build my first Gradle project, I was stack with several problems and I would like to share few tips :

- First of all, make sure that you are using valid Gradle build system. I mean a valid version of Gradle to build android project. The build file which you can see above, I built it with the next configuration :

> ```
> ------------------------------------------------------------
> Gradle 1.10
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Build time:   2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
> Build number: none
> Revision:     36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6
>
> Groovy:       1.8.6
> Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
> Ivy:          2.2.0
> JVM:          1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation 24.51-b03)
> OS:           Linux 3.13.0-32-generic amd64
> ```

- Make sure that old version of Gradle was removed from your local machine. **Why?** Because no guarantee that both Gradle versions will not conflict together.
- Make sure that your build.gradle file is correct and does not contain invalid logic (incorrect dependencies, valid markup structure, etc.)